# How can I improve my current model to get a higher mAP value? (Stuck at 79~78)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, machine-learning-model, object-detection

I am facing an issue trying to improve my model for object detection, this is something which I have been facing for quite a few days. I have tried to improve my model by fine tuning and also changed the split to 80-20 (5399 for train, 1499 for val) to include more data for my validation set but still no luck in trying to improve the mAP (mean average precision) value of my model. The model config I have so far:

```
model_4 = Sequential()

model_4.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(300, 300, 3)))
# model_4.add(RandomFlip(mode='horizontal_and_vertical', seed=None))
model_4.add(BatchNormalization())
model_4.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model_4.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model_4.add(BatchNormalization())
model_4.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model_4.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model_4.add(BatchNormalization())
model_4.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model_4.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model_4.add(BatchNormalization())
model_4.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model_4.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model_4.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model_4.add(Flatten())
model_4.add(Dropout(0.35))
model_4.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
model_4.add(Dropout(0.35))

model_4.add(Dense(4))

model_4.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=[tfr.keras.metrics.MeanAveragePrecisionMetric()])

model_4.summary()
```

My approach is to try and improve as much as I can without a pretrained model/weights. I trianed with batch size as 64, no data augmentation. I was hoping to at least reach 85% or higher but that may be a bit of a stretch for me at this point.

My graphs for loss and mAP:

I reached a mAP of 79 for my train and val set which is quite close
[image: mAP Graph]
[image: loss graph]

Any help would be appreciated as to how I can go forward into making the model perform better. I am sure there has to be something that is causing a bottleneck in the model performance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to consider:

1. Increase the number of convolution blocks.
2. Use residual blocks, as explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-resnet-in-keras-e8f1322a49ba)
3. Use different activation functions, such as Leaky ReLU, Mish, Swish, etc.
4. To connect the feature map of feature extractors to the dense layer, use the Global pooling layer instead of flattening.
5. Try hyperparameter tuning with already available keras tuners.
6. Another approach would be to use an already fine-tuned model using [Transfer Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/transfer-learning-for-deep-learning/#:%7E:text=Transfer%20learning%20is%20an%20optimization,that%20has%20already%20been%20learned.). Take a look at the [EfficentNets](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just have a doubt regarding the first, fifth and sixth point. For the first point, does that mean increase the convolutional layers? If so, won't that make the model less accurate since complexity can cause overfitting. For the fifth point, do you have any reference I can use for keras tuners? Finally for the sixth point, can efficientnets be used for regression task? Since I am not doing classification. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, increasing the number of layers "can" cause overfitting, but trying it with different learning rates and activations such as LeakyReLU which avoid dying ReLU problem,  might be helpful.

Comment: For tuners, See https://keras.io/keras_tuner/

Comment: This paper has used the idea of transfer learning  to solve a regression task: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417418305554